# How to cache a pdf Loaded from url in flutter using syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer or advance_pdf_viewer

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion

I am working on an app that displays pdf from URL(cloud firestore) that is passed from the previous screen to the pdf screen. I want every time the user loads the URL, the pdf should be cached so that no loading is required next time. I tried using **cached_pdf_view** it works but it is missing features and it is giving me problems when scrolling the pdf. I want to use **advance_pdf_viewer** or **syncfusion pdf package** to display the pdf and cache it. I got some help from  https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/165812/cache-pdf-from-network on the package and replaced my code but am getting this new error **FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path** . This is my pdf screen.

```
class PdfScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;
  final String id;

  const PdfScreen({super.key, required this.url, required this.id});
  @override
  _HomePage createState() => _HomePage();
}

class _HomePage extends State<PdfScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<SfPdfViewerState> _pdfViewerKey = GlobalKey();
  File? _tempFile;

  @override
  void initState() {
    initializeFile();
    super.initState();
  }

  //ignore: avoid_void_async
  void initializeFile() async {
    final Directory tempPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final File tempFile = File('${tempPath.path}/${widget.url}');
    final bool checkFileExist = await tempFile.exists();
    if (checkFileExist) {
      _tempFile = tempFile;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget child;
    if (_tempFile == null) {
      print('no temp fille');
      child = SfPdfViewer.network(widget.url, key: _pdfViewerKey,
          onDocumentLoaded: (PdfDocumentLoadedDetails details) async {
        final Directory tempPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        _tempFile = await File('${tempPath.path}/${widget.url}')
            .writeAsBytes(List.from(await details.document.save()));
      });
    } else {
      child = SfPdfViewer.file(
        _tempFile!,
        key: _pdfViewerKey,
      );
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Syncfusion Flutter PDF Viewer'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.bookmark,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              _pdfViewerKey.currentState?.openBookmarkView();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: child,
    );
 `` }
` `}
```